# Return ID of inserted updated record in MERGE command

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I need to insert/update an item into table and return record's ID. Here is my T-SQL:

```
BEGIN
   MERGE [AgentDumps] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS Target
   USING (SELECT @AgentID) AS Source (AgentID)
   ON (target.AgentID = source.AgentID)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE
       Set DumpData = @DumpData,
           UpdateTime = getdate()
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT 
       ([AgentID],
        [DumpData]
       )
     VALUES 
       (
         @AgentID,
         @DumpData
       );
    SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)
  END
```

This works only when new record is inserted. But if the existing one is updated the query return null. I tried to add OUTPUT INSERTED.ID in Update command:

```
BEGIN
   MERGE [AgentDumps] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS Target
   USING (SELECT @AgentID) AS Source (AgentID)
   ON (target.AgentID = source.AgentID)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE
       Set DumpData = @DumpData,
           UpdateTime = getdate()
           OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT 
       ([AgentID],
        [DumpData]
       )
     VALUES 
       (
         @AgentID,
         @DumpData
       );
    SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)
  END
```

But SQL returns: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.

Comment: move `output` to the very end of merge statement

Comment: Works like a charm